# Angular 6 [WDS] Disconnected Error on Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, webpack-dev-server, angular6

I use Angular and i get console error only on Firefox "**[WDS] Disconnected!**".

**[image: Firefox console error message is here]**

Here is my Angular-Cli version.

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.1
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.1
... cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.1
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.1
@angular/animations               6.0.4
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.1
@schematics/angular               0.6.1
@schematics/update                0.6.1
rxjs                              6.2.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.6.0
```

Comment: Your app works on Firefox but you just get a console error? can you try to server your app with Ahead of time compilation and then try firefox again?

Comment: App doesn’t work correctly on Firefox. Some js functions doesnt work. Only Firefox.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Hope I can find a solution...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solved it today by running `npm update`. Apparently it was a bug with an older version of Webpack.

Comment: Do you have a link for that issue at webpack?

Answer (score 9):

This error appeared again for me under angular 7.2.1.

The solution was to add the following line in angular.json under architect>serve>options:

```
"disableHostCheck": true
```

Comment: @BlackFox This applies to the internal server which by itself is a security risk and very clearly announced as such by the CLI, so it's like saying that adding menthol flavor to a cigarette is a health risk.

Comment: I like your comment even though i dont fully understand how an internal server is a security risk. I was hope to point out “kids...dont smoke cigarettes....even if they add mint flavor to it. Learn about the health risk first”. Every other post on StackOverflow about “disableHostCheck” set to true says “ this is.a security risk”. I will venture to understand why this weekend.

Comment: The builtin server shouldn't be used in production because it hasn't been tested for security. It's just for development and should be inaccessible to the outside world. Hence setting disablehostcheck to true doesn't matter in a context which already is insecure.

Comment: Besided the fix, can anyone explain why this error appears?